# What is the benefit in a streamed file upload if you have to read the file into memory in order to protect against large files being uploaded?

Tags: .net, file, streaming, filestream

I have been looking into .Net streamed file uploads for performance using their documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#size-validation

And their sample apps linked from there here:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/e43694e1cdd2c29decd0d45cca5ff78d6b0e2506/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples

Their documentation shows how to prevent large file uploads by using either an attribute such as:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Megabytes.One)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
```

Or a global configuration in ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Megabytes.One;
});
```

The problem is these only work for buffered uploads and I want to do a streamed upload for scaling reasons. As I understand by streaming the file to disk I limit memory usage.

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/e43694e1cdd2c29decd0d45cca5ff78d6b0e2506/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Controllers/StreamingController.cs

The 3.x sample app processes the file like so:

```
// from controller
streamedFileContent = await FileHelpers.ProcessStreamedFile(section, contentDisposition, 
    ModelState, _permittedExtensions, _fileSizeLimit);
```

Which executes the code found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/e43694e1cdd2c29decd0d45cca5ff78d6b0e2506/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Utilities/FileHelpers.cs#L149

but specifically this section:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

    // Check if the file is empty or exceeds the size limit.
    if (memoryStream.Length == 0)
    {
        modelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is empty.");
    }
    else if (memoryStream.Length > sizeLimit)
    {
        var megabyteSizeLimit = sizeLimit / 1048576;
        modelState.AddModelError("File", $"The file exceeds {megabyteSizeLimit:N1} MB.");
    }
    ....
```

So in order to protect against large uploads they are reading the file to memory anyway. In that case I cannot understand the benefit of streaming?

Comment: Honestly, that just seems like a bad example to me; you could, for example, enforce a content-length upload header (although this may preclude some "chunked" uploads), or you could enforce the limit *while reading it* (although I'd actively advocate against buffering to `MemoryStream` in most cases - just handle the input directly)

Comment: @MarcGravell I am thinking of doing as you suggested - enforce while reading/writing the stream to disk, if it goes over stop and delete what was written.

Comment: why buffer *at all*? it most cases it is preferable to process the data *as it streams*

Comment: @MarcGravell if you post an answer Ill accept it